# What is the Extent of Cognito Forms API?

Tags: cognito-forms

I saw that Cognito forms supports webhooks, and form data posting to a chosen server using JSON.

I'm interested to know whether there is any API support to, for example, embed the Cognito form builder and display created forms in a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms can be easily embedded onto a website in three different ways. In you form, go to the publish section to see these options.

The easiest way is a seamless embedding option that will load the Cognito forms library into the client's browser then load the form directly into the website.

This is a useful feature. JSON webhooks will still trigger for submissions sent on embedded websites.

Finally, you can not load the form builder onto an external website, just the forms.